# How to make gcc/g++ warn on comparing signed and unsigned char

Tags: gcc

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test(unsigned char * arg) { }

int main() {
    char *pc = (char *) malloc(1);
    unsigned char *pcu = (unsigned char *) malloc(1);

    *pcu = *pc = -1;                                        /* line 10 */

    if (*pc == *pcu) puts("equal"); else puts("not equal"); /* line 12 */

    pcu = pc;                                               /* line 14 */

    if (pcu == pc) {                                        /* line 16 */

        test(pc);                                           /* line 18 */

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) (but it is not limited to this particular version) with options

```
gcc a.c -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-conversion -Wno-unused-parameter; ./a.out
```

I get the following warnings

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10:21: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘char’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
test.c:14:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
test.c:16:17: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
test.c:18:17: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘test’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
test.c:4:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
not equal
```

g++ warnings/errors are similar. I hope I understand why the comparison on line 12 is evaluated to *false*, but is there any way to get a warning also in such cases? If not, is there some principial difference between line 12 and the lines which cause warnings? Is there any specific reason why comparison of char and unsigned char shouldn't deserve its warning? Because at least at first glance, line 12 seems to me more "dangerous" than e.g. line 16.

A short "story behind": I have to put together pieces of code from various sources. Some of them use char and some of them use unsigned char. `-funsigned-char` would work fine, but I am forced to avoid it and rather to add proper type conversions. That's why such a warning would be useful for me, because now, if I forget to add a type conversion in such a case, the program silently fails.

Thanks in advance, P.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the `char`s to `int`s, it does warn.

Comment: @ams: I guess the difference is that in the case of `char`s both `char` and `unsigned char` are converted to (`signed`) `int`. Then the values are `-1` and `255`, they have *the same type* (so in that time there's no reason for any warning), and of course they are not equal.

Comment: yes, I just wrote up that answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is caused by *integer promotion*.

When you deal with `char` or `short`, what C actually does (and this is defined by the standard, not the implementation) is promote those types to `int` before doing any operations. The theory, I think, is that `int` is supposed to be the natural size used by the underlying machine, and therefore the fastest, most efficient size; in fact, most architectures will do this conversion on loading a byte without being asked.

Since both `signed char` and `unsigned char` will fit happily within the range of a `signed int`, the compiler uses that for both, and *the comparison becomes a pure signed comparison*.

When you have a mismatched type on the left-hand-side of the expression (lines 10 and 14) then it needs to convert that back to the smaller type, but it can't, so you get a warning.

When you compared the mismatching pointers (line 16) and passed the mismatching pointer (line 18), the integer promotion is not in play because you never actually dereference the pointers, and so no integers are ever compared (`char` is an integer type also, of course).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure, whether I got the point. I hope I do (somehow :-) understand how all these things work, but I wanted to say that comparing char and unsigned char seems to me more dangerous than some other situations which produce a warning, namely the line 16 or e.g. the warning on unused function parameter (which is turned off in my scenario). That's why I am curious why such a comparisons do not produce a warning.

Comment: The point is that comparing signed and unsigned char *is safe* as long as you don't actually expect `(-1 == 255) == true`. There's no undefined behaviour there.

Comment: I hope that declared but unused parameters and variables are safe also, and the warning exists. So the difference is that in all the other cases except line 12 the standard is not strict, IOW that the result is not defined by the standard, but by the particular compiler implementation --- and that gcc warnings actually do not mean something like "hey, this is pretty weird, are you sure", but they only warn me the result is compiler dependent? I have thought that the former is right, but may be I have been wrong. :-)

Comment: Some warnings are there to help you spot half-written code (you wrote to a variable, but then forgot to use it later, or you removed a variable but missed the declaration). Some are there to steer you around pitfalls. Some are there because your code violates a constraint in the standard, but the compiler is being permissive.